# Bash Serial Scripting

Tags: bash, serial-port

I am connecting to a modem over a serial port and trying to figure out how to send an AT command, and add conditionals depending on the output. I can connect using `screen` or `minicom` to /dev/ttyAMA0 and send the `AT` command and receive the response `OK`, but when I use

```
echo -en "AT" >/dev/ttyAMA0 && cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I only see what I am echoing, not what the response is. I need to be able to send the `AT` command, check to see if the output is OK, or ERROR, then based off that response, do something different. Why am I not getting any response from the serial device?

I am trying to create a bash script that can connect to the modem and send a text message, but need to know if there are errors rather than just blasting things through assuming it is working. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Scripting a dialog through a terminal-like port is a complex enough problem that people have written special tools to do it; the classic is [the Expect/Tcl library](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html).  I think Tcl is simple to learn, but there are [Expect bindings for other scripting languages](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3883).

I found [this script](https://gist.github.com/ubinix-warun/9722490) that uses Expect to communicate over a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

After echoing you cannot simply cat the device file. You need to start a listening loop:

```
while read -r str < /dev/ttyAMA0; do
  # $str will contain a line of text returned from modem.
done
```

Comment: I don't understand why I can't just cat the device? When I have it open in two terminals, I see all the AT commands I put into terminal 1 on terminal 2 that has `cat /dev/ttyAMA0` running. With this loop, I didn't see anything at all returned to the `read` variable.

Comment: I used this method and it worked fine. Sorry if this is not universal in all cases. And btw you need to check $str variable